# how to parse Freebase topic api response with gson

Tags: java, json, gson, freebase

is it possible to parse the json response returned by the Freebase experimental TOPIC Api with the google gson library?
i have used gson to parse the json repsone from multiple freebase mqlread responses.
i am now stuck attempting to parse json messages like the response from this

http://api.freebase.com/api/experimental/topic/basic?id=/en/sgt_peppers_lonely_hearts_club_band

or from this

http://api.freebase.com/api/experimental/topic/basic?id=/en/please_please_me,/en/sgt_peppers_lonely_hearts_club_band

or this

http://api.freebase.com/api/experimental/topic/standard?id=/guid/9202a8c04000641f800000000de75560&domains=all

is it possible to parse all three repsones with one gson "code set"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried to do this but there is no reason why it wouldn't work. Are you getting any errors when you use it ? If you paste your code and errors I might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer to this question:

[Stuck on parsing a JSON response to a Java Object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884658/stuck-on-parsing-a-json-response-to-a-java-object-in-android)

The same approach should work for the Topic API.

Comment: thanks for your response your link is broken though i think it should be this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884658/stuck-on-parsing-a-json-response-to-a-java-object-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on GSON and switched to JACKSON
it works perfectly for extracting the data of interest and ignoring everything else.
thanks for all the time spent in responding to my question